# dataproc create cluster gcloud equivalent command in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, dataproc

How do I replicate the following gcloud command in python?

```
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create spark-nlp-cluster \
     --region global \
     --metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=google-cloud-storage spark-nlp==2.5.3' \
     --worker-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
     --num-workers 2 \
     --image-version 1.4-debian10 \
     --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/python/pip-install.sh \
     --optional-components=JUPYTER,ANACONDA \
     --enable-component-gateway
```

Here is what I have so far in python:

```
    cluster_data = {
        "project_id": project,
        "cluster_name": cluster_name,
        "config": {
            "gce_cluster_config": {"zone_uri": zone_uri},
            "master_config": {"num_instances": 1, "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-1"},
            "worker_config": {"num_instances": 2, "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-1"},
            "software_config":{"image_version":"1.4-debian10","optional_components":{"JUPYTER","ANACONDA"}}
            
        },
    }

    cluster = dataproc.create_cluster(
        request={"project_id": project, "region": region, "cluster": cluster_data}
    )
```

Not sure how to convert these gcloud commands to python:

```
     --metadata 'PIP_PACKAGES=google-cloud-storage spark-nlp==2.5.3' \  
     --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/python/pip-install.sh \
     --enable-component-gateway
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as this :

```
cluster_data = {
    "project_id": project,
    "cluster_name": cluster_name,
    "config": {
        "gce_cluster_config": {"zone_uri": zone_uri},
        "master_config": {"num_instances": 1, "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-1"},
        "worker_config": {"num_instances": 2, "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-1"},
        "software_config":{"image_version":"1.4-debian10","optional_components":{"JUPYTER","ANACONDA"}},
        "initialization_actions":{"executable_file" : "gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/python/pip-install.sh"},
        "gce_cluster_config": {"metadata": "PIP_PACKAGES=google-cloud-storage,spark-nlp==2.5.3"},
        "endpoint_config": {"enable_http_port_access":True},
        
    },
}
```

You can access for more : [GCP Cluster Configs](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dataproc.v1#google.cloud.dataproc.v1.ClusterConfig)